# Seed Stack W20 Framework where to include service js file in configuration

Tags: java, angularjs, stack, seed

I have created a factory within seed stack w20 framework, need to know how to include that factory js file in seed stack configuration? I have modules folder which contains all modules, view folder that contains all views & have created service folder which will contain all service files, within which have declared my factory to retrieve data from API. I want to include this factory on a view page, so where should i specify the declaration for the same.